# Java server program for non line-oriented application-level protocol

Tags: java, network-programming

I am writing a server application in Java. To read from the socket i have:

```
line = in.readLine();
```

where `in` is a `BufferReader` instance so i can read strings from the socket stream.

How can i change that to adopt my program to a non line-oriented protocol, where the end of each application-level message is supposded to be terminated by a special charachter, e.g. `%`, and not a newline charachter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) method in a loop until the character is `%`. At each character, append it to a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = reader.read(); i >= 0; i = reader.read()) {
    char c = (char) i;
    if (c == '%') {
        break; // or consume the current builder, and recreate a new one
    }
    else {
        builder.append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not because the BufferedReader will take care of buffering the reads. That's the main reason to use a BufferedReader.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice he was using BufferedReader. I thought it was a normal InputStream. +1 then.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't actually used this myself, I did recall seeing this class in the documentation a while ago and it does look like it could do what you want, even tho its functionality might be a bit overkill for just separating input.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

This would allow you to directly wrap your `BufferedReader` in a `StreamTokenizer` after which you can set it up to recognize the `%` character as a whitespace character, and every other caracter as a ordinary/alphabetic character. Then you can repeatedly call `nextToken` on the tokenizer and while it returns `TT_WORD` you can get the token through the `sval` attribute.

In the end it might however be easier to just implement this yourself according to JB Nizet's reply.